# JaCoCo test coverage of ant based Netbean Module project

Tags: unit-testing, netbeans, ant, jacoco

We have inherited a `NetBeans` Modules project (a.k.a. `NetBeans` Platform project) which builds using the `NetBeans` `Ant` tasks. We want to generate a code coverage report of the project to get an idea of what components are not being unit tested. 
Generating a report is not part of the build process, it is simply something we want to do to understand the existing unit test coverage in the project.

We've decided to use `JaCoCo` to try and generate this. However the native support in `NetBeans` is for maven based projects. Unfortunately the [TikiOne JaCoCoverage plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/48570/tikione-jacocoverage) currently does not support `NetBeans` Modules projects.

We are happy to just drive this via `CLI` to get an initial report. Does anyone have a success means of doing so under the given constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have been successful in generating the report by doing the following:

1. Edited the `project.properties` file to run the JaCoCo agent when unit tests run. This is done by adding the following:

   ```
   test.run.args=-javaagent:[yourpath/]jacocoagent.jar=destfile=[yourpath/]jacoco.exec
   ```
2. Use Netbeans to run the `test` task. This produces the `jacoco.exec` file.
3. Create a simple ant buildfile to generate reports from an `.exec` file (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973067/how-to-use-jacoco-exec-report))
4. Run the ant buildfile to generate the report.

Comment: For the LIFE of me I simply cannot get this to work.  How can you tell if Netbeans is actually executing this agent?

Answer (score 0):

Someone recently posted a related message to one of NetBeans mailing lists - https://netbeans.org/projects/platform/lists/dev/archive/2014-04/message/124

Short version: Cobertura plugin that does what you're looking for is not maintained now but you can build it and run it.

Comment: Thanks, we tried using Cobertura first, but were having issues with dependencies. In the latest stable release (v2.0.3) the bundled JARs do not match what the shell script includes. This seemed to be the case across all v2 releases.