# Need to generate Code Coverage Reports using jacoco.exec file

Tags: java, jboss, code-coverage, jacoco

I have application war file deployed on Jboss 7 server. I able to generate `jacoco.exec` file by adding following JVM option

```
javaagent:/jboss/common/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/root/jacoco/jacoco.exec,includes=*,append=true,output=file
```

I want to have code coverage report generated automatically without using eclipse/ plugins.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: I have jacoco.exec file generated . But I want to generate code coverage html reports using this .exec file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use jacoco.exec report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973067/how-to-use-jacoco-exec-report)

Comment: I am able to generate the jacoco.exec report but the repport coming empty. Any idea what might go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to generate jacoco reports using following steps:

Step A: Modify / add JVM option in conf file
../jboss/bin/run.conf
JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:../jboss/common/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/opt/jacoco/jacoco.exec,includes=*,excludes=org.*,append=true,output=file

Step B:Copy jacocoagent.jar jar file in jboss lib directory
../jboss/lib/jacocoagent.jar

Step C: Perform manual testing

Step D: Shutdown Jboss instance. jacoco.exec file will get generated.

Step E: Write build.xml ant file to generate reports[html,csv,xml] based on .exec file , mentioning path for jacocoagent jar file

Step G: Run build.xml ant. This step will generate the report finally.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct way. Btw, I use append mode as "false". I also denote jacoco.exec file in this case as either jacocoIT.exec (for Integraiton tests) or jacocoAT.exec (acceptance tests) or etc (jacocoST.exe for Selenium tests) as all these are kind of non-Unit tests (which require external resources for the tests to run).