# Cobertura generating incorrect code coverage

Tags: java, junit, maven-cobertura-plugin

I have a huge code base configured using maven. My codebase is divided in different maven modules and thus I have a main pom file and each sub module has its own pom file. But still these modules call each other's functionality. Junit tests are written for each module. I am using Cobertura to generate code coverage. Its generating separate coverage report for each module. When Cobertura generate code coverage for module A and a perticular code from Module A is getting called by tests from module B. In this scenario Cobertura marks that code from Module A as uncovered. Is this the expected behavior? Or I have wrong configuration?

Maven - Cobertura Configuration in submodules:

build section:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
```

Reporting section:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${org.codehaus.mojo.cobertura-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <formats>
                        <format>xml</format>
                    </formats>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Command to run Cobertura report:

```
mvn cobertura:cobertura
```

Comment: please guide me on this.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to try JaCoCo code coverage tool for the run-time coverage generation, which is easier to implement and more expressive in terms of code covered[package,class,method,line]. 
It provides additional features compared to Cobertura.
I tried JaCoCo and other tools and found JaCoCo generated reports more comprehensible and useful, compared to other.

Refer:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Comparison+of+code+coverage+tools
[Need to generate Code Coverage Reports using jacoco.exec file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108661/need-to-generate-code-coverage-reports-using-jacoco-exec-file/31383356#31383356)

Comment: Will try Jacoco. Will it cover tests ran on other modules as well (as mentioned in the question?)

Comment: Yes. It will cover all modules deployed under that server.