# need to generate report from jacoco.exec

Tags: report, jacoco

I had tried below solution but it is not getting result from this.
[how to use jacoco.exec report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973067/how-to-use-jacoco-exec-report)
[Need to generate Code Coverage Reports using jacoco.exec file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31108661/need-to-generate-code-coverage-reports-using-jacoco-exec-file)

But I am not able to generate reports.Could you please help me to complete this.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: I am new in stack over flow . Everybody here is not giving me ans they are just questioning me inappropriately.

Comment: How is it inappropriate to ask you to improve your question and follow site norms?

Comment: There's simply not enough information here for us to help you because you don't show your code.

Comment: OK Thanks got your point.